# Copy a list of folder to another folder?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

Is there anyway so I can copy a list of folders within a text file to another folder in Windows?

I have a text like this:

```
87312
87313 
87314 
87315
...
```

I assume it's possible via Powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your text file contains the entire pathes to the folders you want to copy (each line may be a path), here is a script that may be usefull for you :

```
$folders = Get-Content C:\Users\Antoine\Desktop\folders.txt
foreach ($folder in $folders)
{
    Copy-Item -path $folder -destination C:\Test3 -Recurse

}
```

You just have to modify the path to your text file, and the destination.

Hope this helps !